# Apache Baikal server RewriteRule for CardDAV short URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using Baikal CalDAV and CardDAV server to keep my contacts and calendars in sync. It works pretty well with all of my clients. For iPhone and Mac suppoer I even put `/.well-known/` redirect rules in my Apache vHost file.

Contacts Sync is work on the following URL:

```
myurl/html/card.php/principals/(username)
```

I would like to make this URL shorter for other users. I thought I could do it with `mod_rewrite` on Apache but I couldn't make it work.

I want to rewrite

```
myurl/(username)
```

to

```
myurl/html/card.php/principals/(username)
```

It looks really simple but I mostly ended up with recursive redirects. I used following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /html/card.php/principals/$1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  it's a rewrite loop error.

`(.*)` matches any uri including the destination uri and rewrites it back to itself causing an infinite loop error.

To avoid this error, we need to exclude the path we are rewriting to.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/html/card.php/principal/
RewriteRule (.*) /html/card.php/principal/$1
```

Now the rule is conditional, it will rewrite **/foo** to **/html/card.php/principal/foo**  it will not rewrite **/html/card.php/principal/foo** to **/html/card.php/principal/foo** .

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your help. I read lots of documentation about RewriteRule but missed that RewriteCond usage. It's really appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, from **mydomain.com/card-12345** to **mydomain.com/dav.php/addressbooks/12345/default**, but I still have a 404 error...